# Deploying React front end with Django session based auth doesnt work over HTTPS

Tags: django, cookies, django-rest-framework, web-deployment, django-csrf

So I have a working LOCAL Twitter clone called Hater but cant deploy front end b/c I cant access secured Cookies(https://github.com/mustafabin/hater)

I used Django's built-in Session-based auth I have middleware all set up

LOGIN VIEW

```
@method_decorator(csrf_protect, name="dispatch")
class LoginView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        data = self.request.data

        username = data['username']
        password = data['password']

        try:
            user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                auth.login(request, user)
                return Response({'success': 'User authenticated'})
            else:
                return Response({'error': 'Error Authenticating'})
        except:
            return Response({'error': 'Something went wrong when logging in'})
```

SIGN UP

```
@method_decorator(csrf_protect, name="dispatch")
class SignupView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        data = self.request.data

        username = data['username']
        password = data['password']
        re_password = data['re_password']
        tag = data['tag']

        try:
            if password == re_password:
                if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                    return Response({"error": "Username already exists"})
                else:
                    if len(password) < 6:
                        return Response({"error": "Password must be at least 6 characters"})
                    else:
                        user = User.objects.create_user(
                            username=username, password=password)

                        user = User.objects.get(id=user.id)

                        user_profile = User_profile.objects.create(
                            user=user, name=username, tag=tag)

                        return Response({'success': "User created successfully"})
            else:
                return Response({'error': "Passwords do not match"})
        except:
            return Response({"error": "Something went wrong signing up"})
```

I'm aware some of these settings are redundant but ur man got desperate

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['http://localhost:3000', 'http://localhost:8000',
                        'https://hater.netlify.app', 'https://haterip.netlify.app']
CORS_EXPOSE_HEADERS = ["Set-Cookie"]
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

and this is React.js code that handles login and the terinary that displays the login form when user isnt logged in user.tag is a global state that is null if no current user is logged in

```
let handleLogin = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let headerInfo = {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    };
    let loginOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: headerInfo,
      credentials: "include",
      body: JSON.stringify(form),
    };
    let options = {
      method: "GET",
      headers: headerInfo,
      credentials: "include",
    };

    fetch(`https://haterbackend.herokuapp.com/user/login`, loginOptions)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        if (data["error"]) {
          return alert(data["error"]);
        } else {
          fetch(`https://haterbackend.herokuapp.com/user/grabProfile`, options)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
              store.dispatch({ type: "set", payload: data.profile });
            })
            .then(() => navigate("/home"))
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
  {!user.tag ? (
      <form onSubmit={handleLogin} className="landingForm">
        <CSRFToken></CSRFToken>
        <input
          onChange={handleChange}
          className="landingLoginInput"
          placeholder="Username"
          type="text"
          name="username"
        />

        <input
          onChange={handleChange}
          className="landingLoginInput"
          placeholder="Password"
          type="password"
          name="password"
          autoComplete="current-password"
        />
        <Button id="login" type="submit">
          Login
        </Button>
      </form>
    ) : (
      <div className="landing-signout">
        <Link className="landing-home-link" to="/home">
          <Button>Home </Button>
        </Link>
        <Link className="landing-signout-link" onClick={signOut} to="/">
          <Button>Sign out </Button>
        </Link>
      </div>
    )}
```

The CSRFToken componet is just a hidden input field

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function CSRFToken() {
  const [csrftoken, setcsrftoken] = useState("");

  const getCookie = (name) => {
    let cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== "") {
      let cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
      for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        let cookie = cookies[i].trim();
        if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === name + "=") {
          cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    return cookieValue;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://haterbackend.herokuapp.com/user/csrf_cookie`, {
      credentials: "include",
    })
      .then((res) => {
        setcsrftoken(getCookie("csrftoken"));
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value={csrftoken || ""} />
  );
}
```

I implemented session login with react front end as outlined here:
https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/django-csrf-protection-guide/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/csrf/#ajax official doc

the method above only worked locally on HTTP but wouldnt work over HTTPS because the deployed site wouldnt set the cookie because it wasnt secured
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTOvO.png)

But client side scripts cant grab secure cookies and the getCookie function from the Django docs only parses thru a set cookie header so it wouldnt work if the cookie is undefined or empty ( client side script code attempts to read the cookie, the browser returns an empty string as the result source linked below)
https://owasp.org/www-community/HttpOnly

TLDR: Project works locally HTTP but when deployed cookies cant be set over HTTPS but client-side scripts cant read secure cookies so i cant register or log users in because that requires the csrftoken cookie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Super late reply but its not possible to securely use session based auth when my backend service was deployed on a different domain.

front end was on netifly
back end was on heroku

a better alternative that I used was django knox tokens it behaves the same way as JWT authentication but has more functionality and tokens can be invalidated.

TLDR; because the services were not under the same domain its not possible under a https connection